# How to do clear screen on Apache Felix Gogo shell?

Tags: java, terminal, liferay, osgi, apache-felix

I'm using Liferay DXP. When using the Apache Felix gogo shell, **I cannot find how to do a clear-screen?** Just like cls in windows and clear on Mac / Linux. Screen grows very long and I have to do close the terminal manually and then open it up again. Hitting CTRL / CMD + C on Windows / Linux will stop the OSGI server and I had to restart my server again, which is never my option.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Gogo JLine shell (`org.apache.felix.gogo.jline`) then the `clear` command works.

However if you are using the plain shell (`org.apache.felix.gogo.shell`) there is no way to do this... except hitting Return lots of times I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my own answer :-) On command line there is no way. But if you're starting the server in Eclipse, you can see the gogo shell by right-clicking the server and `Open GOGO shell`. In eclipse terminal you can clear it BY clicking `Clear terminal` icon located on the top right of terminal window.